# Other pins always lighting up

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

Why is the other pins lighting up, even though I haven't set `digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);` already?

I don't know what's making the other pins light up the LED.

Here is my code:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, i = 4;

void setup() {
  for (i = 4; i <= 13; i++) {
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }
  for (i = 4; i <= 8; i++) {
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
  }
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    x += 1;
  }
  if (x == 3) {
    i += 1;
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
    x = 0;
  }

  if (digitalRead(3) == HIGH) {
    y -= 1;
  }
  if (y == 3) {
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
    i -= 1;
    y = 0;
  }
}
```

I tested it (without breadboard yet ...) through the Arduino board itself, and the built-in LED or the `LED_BUILTIN` is lighting up, but the light level is not too high; it is like it is dimmed.

Now, I tested it using the breadboard by manually connecting a jumper wire from one pin to the other.  All of the pins makes the LED light up, but I don't understand, because my code doesn't allow the other pins, except for pins 4 to 8, to light up.

So, basically, what I want my code to achieve, is to light up 1 LED (+1 LED), every three clicks on the button (pin 2).  On the other hand, I also want it to turn off 1 LED (-1 LED), every three clicks on the button (pin 3).  But, before clicking, pins 4 to 8 are already lighted (as you can see on the `void setup()`).

Comment: What kind of LEDs are you using?

Comment: @jikuja What do you mean, kind of LED?  Is there any types of LEDs?  If there is, then I'm probably using just a regular or a normal red / yellow / green LED.

Comment: `digitalWrite(i, HIGH)` and `digitalWrite(i, LOW)` will turn LEDs' ON/OFF. Have you connected pin `2` and `3` to something?

Comment: Which pins are you expecting to light up and which ones are you calling "other" pins?

Comment: @Delta_G the only pins I'm expecting to light up were pins 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8.  The "other" pins were pins 9 to 13.

Comment: Hi!  I'd edited the question.  Check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem myself ...

```
if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    x += 1;
}
```

There should be a `delay` after the `x += 1;`, like this: ...

```
if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    x += 1;
    delay(200);
}
```

So, the `x` should not be increasing immediately.

New Code:

```
int x = 0, y = 0, i = 7;

void setup() {
  for (int a = 4; a <= 13; a++) {
    pinMode(a, OUTPUT);
  }
  for (int a = 4; a <= 7; a++) {
    digitalWrite(a, HIGH);
  }
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH) {
    x += 1;
    delay(200);
  }
  if (x == 3) {
    i += 1;
    digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
    x = 0;
  }

  if (digitalRead(3) == HIGH) {
    y += 1;
    delay(200);
  }
  if (y == 3) {
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
    i -= 1;
    y = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `setup()` you turn on a bunch of pins:

```
for (i = 4; i <= 13; i++) { // set pins 4-13 up as outputs
  pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
}
for (i = 4; i <= 8; i++) { // turn on 4,5,6,7, and 8
  digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
```

The rest of your code in loop does nothing to turn them off, so they stay on.

And later, assuming your `digitalRead()` statements are connected to pushing some buttons, with no delay or other mechanism to slow things down, the following statements could be executed faster than you can control:

```
i += 1;
digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
```

I bet if you examine the values for `i` you'll see that they increasing beyond 8 under your testing conditions.  Hence the other pins you set up as output are being turned on from a single (however brief) button press.

Comment: Hey, @TomServo !  I'd edited my question.  Check it out!